# Tipo que no se valida en el contexto actual - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

Al crear el modelo en el método:

```
public int AddEmpleados(Empleados e)
{
    try
    {
        db.Empleados.Add(Empleados);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return 1;
    }     
}
```

En  la propiedad empleados me registra el error empleados es tipo que no se valida en el contexto actual.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, y explícate mejor por que no se entiende nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que estás intentando es agregar un elemento al `DbSet<Empleados>` mediante el método `.Add`, debes agregar el **objeto**, no la **clase** en sí.

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
public int AddEmpleados(Empleados e)
{
   try
   {
       db.Empleados.Add(e);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return 1;
   }     
}
```

Comment: se  soluciono el error   con el cambio   de clase  a objeto